# Jackson Databind Issue - Gradle

Tags: gradle, jackson, apache-storm

I tried to deploy strom Topology written with 2.2.0 at local with below command:

`./storm local ./sample.jar com.sample.processor.storm.Main config.yml`

But unfortunately, I got this issue:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
Could not initialize class
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JdkDeserializers
```

I had included this at gradle file , provided below the gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.0.1"
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "http://clojars.org/repo"}
    maven { url "https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/" }
    jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
}

configurations {
    includeInJar
}

dependencies {
    includeInJar 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13'
    includeInJar 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.12'
    includeInJar 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8'

    compile ('org.apache.storm:storm-core:2.2.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core'
    }
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13'
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.12'
 
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.8'
}
```

Compilation is successful, I was able to test at IDE at runtime, but only during local deployment, above error occurs

Any help appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Same gradle-file worked with storm 0.10.0 but not working at 2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

I removed fasterxml dependencies from gradle build as this conflicts with jackson library and it builds JAR executable fine.